# Distilling milligram quantities of oil like it's late 1970s

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, history-of-chemistry, distillation, separation-techniques

In [a currently retracted](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/15213773#statement)* manuscript by Tomas Hudlicky [[1](https://doi.org/10.1002/ange.202006717), [Retraction Watch](https://retractionwatch.com/2020/06/08/controversial-essay-at-german-chemistry-journal-leads-to-suspensions/)] the following has been noted:

> 6. Fifty years ago professors took an active part in all laboratory instructions and they taught 
>      advanced techniques to research undergraduates, graduate students, and even postdocs.
>      During my postdoctoral stay in Geneva Professor Oppolzer personally showed me how to distill 3 mg of 
>      an oil after I commented that it could not be done.
>      Such practices are all but absent at present. 
>      Students are not taught by professors, most of whom have not been at the bench for decades, but 
>      by more senior personnel in the research laboratory.

Does anyone know or can suggest a plausible method used by Prof. Wolfgang Oppolzer to distill milligram amounts of oil, considering this demonstration has likely took place between 1977 and 1978 (according to [this CV](http://komppasymposium.aalto.fi/Speakers/Hudlicky/Tomas%20Hudlicky%20CV.pdf))?

I flipped through *the* distillation handbook of that time [2], especially focusing on section *5.1.1 Micro- and semi-micro-distillation*, and I suppose it was possible that some version of an extremely miniaturized distillation apparatus combined with a set of spinning band columns or concentric tube columns operating under reduced pressure could've been used:

> The separation of essential oils with spinning band columns at 4 to 13 torr has been reported by Spiegelberg [9].
>   Examples of separations of high-molecular organic compounds with a concentric tube column are given by Jantzen and Witgert [3] and Fischer [7].

Bonus question: how relevant mastering this distillation technique would be these days?
Are there better alternatives and what are they? (Gas chromatography, I presume?)

---

* Thanks to [M. Farooq](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/66245/m-farooq) for drawing my attention towards the article and motivating to find and actually read the original paper.

#### References

1. Hudlicky, T. “Organic Synthesis—Where Now?” Is Thirty Years Old. A Reflection on the Current State of Affairs. *Angew. Chem.* **2020**, ange.202006717. DOI: [10.1002/ange.202006717](https://doi.org/10.1002/ange.202006717). (Retracted 2020-06-05)
2. Krell, E. *Handbook of Laboratory Distillation: With an Introduction into the Pilot Plant Distillation*, completely rev. 2nd ed.; Techniques and instrumentation in analytical chemistry; Elsevier Scientific Pub. Co. ; Elsevier North-Holland: Amsterdam; New York, **1982**. ISBN 978-0-444-99723-4.

Comment: During the 1970's we used a homemade Kugelrohr for non-fractionating distillation of small amounts of liquid under reduced pressure. Today there are hi-tech Kugelrohrs: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelrohr

Comment: Today, in order to purify 3 mg sample, one would do a semi-preparative liquid chromatography or supercritical fluid chromatography (preferred). It is not a big deal today. GC columns have very poor capacity.

Comment: @Andselisk, If you search microdistillation in ACS *Analytical Chemistry*, you will find plenty of apparatus descriptions until the 1960s.